# Fetching data and display dynamically JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch

I wonder what is wrong with the following code. I am trying to fetch data from an API and to display data. The idea is that I create a new innerHTML and display the data from the response in the newly created node. The problem is that I am only able to retrieve one image out of 6.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <body>  
  <main class="main-area">  
      <div class="centered">
          <section class="cards">    
          </section><!-- .cards -->   
      </div><!-- .centered -->     
  </main>

    <script src="./src/index.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
```

And here is index.js:

```
const url = 'https://api.taboola.com/1.2/json/apitestaccount/recommendations.get?app.type=web&app.apikey=7be65fc78e52c11727793f68b06d782cff9ede3c&source.id=%2Fdigiday-publishing-summit%2F&source.url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.taboola.com%2Fdigiday-publishing-summit%2F&source.type=text&placement.organic-type=mix&placement.visible=true&placement.available=true&placement.rec-count=6&placement.name=Below%20Article%20Thumbnails&placement.thumbnail.width=640&placement.thumbnail.height=480&user.session=init'
const newSection = document.querySelector('.cards')


const init = () => {
  fetch(url)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    const article = document.createElement('article');
    article.className = 'card'
    let infos = data.list

    infos.map(el => {
      article.innerHTML = `
      <a href="${el.url}">
          <picture class="thumbnail">
              <img src="${el.thumbnail[0].url}" alt="${el.name}">
          </picture>
          <div class="card-content">
              <h2>${el.name}</h2>
              <p class="branding"><small>${el.branding}</small></p>
          </div>
      </a>
    `
    })

    return newSection.append(article)

  })
}

init()
```

Result: Only one image with name, branding, and the URL is displayed. I tried to use forEach() instead of map(), still not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

- In your code, you have called `image.map()`.
- The `map()` function in javascript only works for arrays, so when you used it on an image an error was thrown.
- Therefore, to get rid of this particular error, replace the `h2` part of your code with something like the following:

`<h2>This is an image</h2>`

Or whatever you want the image to be called. You can find the title of the image source by using

`document.getElementByID("imagename").src`

Answer (score 0):

There are still 2 issues with your edited code:

1. There's no `newSection` element reference in your code, so nothing can be appended to it.
2. You've created `article` element out of your `infos.map()` so it's created only once.

Your loop should look like this:

```
data.list.map(el => {
  var innerContent = `
        <a href="${el.url}">
            <picture class="thumbnail">
                <img src="${el.thumbnail[0].url}" alt="${el.name}">
            </picture>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2>${el.name}</h2>
                <p class="branding"><small>${el.branding}</small></p>
            </div>
        </a>
        `;
  var card = document.createElement('div');
  card.className = 'card';
  card.innerHTML = innerContent;
  cardsContainer.appendChild(card);
});
```

Comment: thank you, I am now able to retrieve the correct data, but even though I use a map(), the final result in my HTML is that I only get one image out of 6. Any idea?

Comment: Since you edited your question altogether, I also edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. It works now. (I am new in the community, I wanted to upvote your answer but I don't have enough credit! If you upvote my question maybe I can upvote yours)